# Domain and Scope

Tags: word-request

Consider the following areas:

[image]

I think I can say the **scope of B** is A, to point to the region in which the `B` is meaningful (The A area). But from the perspective of A, what can I call this region? (The domain of A ?) I first thought it is the **scope of A** but it is usually referred as the [scope of B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29)!

Need a technical term in software engineering and XML stuff, like the scope itself. I myself think the region is the A context.

Comment: B is a sub-domain of A ?

Comment: @amblina yes, it is

Comment: You want to know what to call 'A' when it contains multiple subdomains e.g. 'B'?  You should be able to say 'the scope of A'.  Can you give context as to what context you want to talk about this.  Are you talking about this in a software development context or something else?

Comment: @amblina I did in the question, but the scope of A is a bigger area which has surrounded the A.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, "scope of X" refers to the scope *within* X, not the scope in which it resides. Occasionally, especially in programming, it's useful to discuss things that have no scope within them, and for which, in that context, the only relevant point is the scope in which they reside. In those cases, reversing the usual rule is acceptable.

This is not one of those cases, since in XML in particular it is quite rare for anything except attributes to have no scopes within them. So I would recommend using "context" for the outer scope, or failing that, "parent scope": the context of B is unambiguously A's inner scope here.

Answer (score 1):

> Need a technical term in software engineering and XML stuff

...

Scope behaves differently in different programming languages.  For that reason alone, "context" is probably better suited to your purposes than 'scope'.  **B** could be called a *nested context* or a *sub-context*.